# How do you force Axis2 to use HTTP 1.0 for a webservice call?

Tags: java, apache-axis, chunking

I'm having issues accessing a web service provided by a third party. Looking at the Axis2 wire trace I can see **\r\n3ff8\r\n** in the middle of my the XML tags coming back which is causing Axis2 to have a hissy fit when it tries to parse them.

As far as I can tell this has something to do with HTTP 1.1 chunking which Axis2 isn't handling very well.

The issue I'm having is Identical to the issue in [this forum post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Java-Development/Getting-Soap-response-with-Errors/td-p/22385)

How can I change the my webservice code to make it use HTTP 1.0 to avoid the chunking issue? As far as I can tell Axis defaults to CommonsHTTPSender anyway so I'm unsure why the forum post linked above suggested changing to that.

Alternatively is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly turn off chunking:

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);
```

You can also control both of these things through the axis2.xml config file, if you'd prefer. Find the following section:

```
<transportSender name="http"
    class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
    <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

You can change the PROTOCOL parameter to "HTTP/1.0", or remove the Transfer-Encoding parameter to disable chunking.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it, get the stub object that you you will use to call the service and add the following code after it:

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```